# What does basic solution mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Linear programming: basic solution?

If the matrix consists of 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&0&0\\-3&6&1&3&0\\0&0&2&6&-1\end{bmatrix},$$
how is it that there are 4 basic solutions? It says that the first and second columns, as well as the third and fourth columns are scalar multiples, but what does that have to do with basic solutions?

Comment: A basic solution is the intersection of two or more constraints. If these are the only constraints (no sign restrictions), then there is a mistake somewhere. The second comment is about basic variables, not basic solutions (slightly different).

Comment: Er...what are you talking about here, to begin with? Is the given matrix the extended one of a linear system in 4 unknowns and thus the last *column* is what we have at the right of the equality sign, or it is a coefficients matrix of a homogeneous system in 5 unknowns??

Answer (score 2):

Your question only makes sense to me if the matrix given is the coefficient matrix for the constraints.  Let's denote that matrix $A$.  Each column in $A$ corresponds to a variable.  Let's suppose these are $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,$ and $x_5$.

**There is a one-to-one correspondence between (1) bases of the column space of $A$ that consist of columns of $A$ and (2) basic solutions to the linear program.**  (That's why they're called *basic solutions*.)  Since columns 1 and 2 are linearly dependent, they can't both be in a basis of the column space of $A$.  Similarly for columns 3 and 4.  Thus there are four bases for the column space of $A$ that can be formed by choosing columns from $A$:

- Column vectors 1, 3, and 5
- Column vectors 1, 4, and 5
- Column vectors 2, 3, and 5
- Column vectors 2, 4, and 5

This means that there are four basic solutions to the linear program; i.e., those in which the following are the basic variables:

- $\{x_1, x_3, x_5\}$
- $\{x_1, x_4, x_5\}$
- $\{x_2, x_3, x_5\}$
- $\{x_2, x_4, x_5\}$

Depending on the right-hand sides of the constraints, not all of the basic solutions may be feasible, but your question does not ask about feasibility.